Odd wiper problem on Mercedes E320 W211 - diagnostic message 'Communication with componentM6/1 wiper motor interrupted'
I have a strange issue with my wipers on my Mercedes E320 W211, they seem to have a mind of their own. No matter what I set the stalk to: off, intermittent 1, 2, on low speed or on high speed I get the same behavior. Whether the weather is wet or not the wipers will wipe, sometimes intermittent, sometimes at low or high speeds, and sometimes they'll stop even if it's pouring. When they stop it's only for a few seconds, then they'll go again, but there's no predicting it. The washers work sometimes, only if the wipers are going already. When it's operating intermittently it seems to wipe according to rain sensor data, most of the time.
When I start the car the wipers won't start going for a few minutes, then they'll go back to the same behavior. All other functions on the indicator stalk, i.e. the turn signals and hi beams work fine. The radio, navigation, climate and everything else works fine. I scanned it with my iCarsoft and got code 9050 with a current state, with the message 'Communication with component M6/1 (Wiper Motor) interrupted'.
I think that the indicator stalk sends data to the front SAM, which gets data from the rain sensor, and powers the wiper motor through a relay. The fuse is obviously working, otherwise the wipers wouldn't work at all.
My thinking is about these potential parts:

Indicator stalk: my first instinct was to suspect this part, however I'm not sure that makes sense now. If it failed I would expect the wipers would be stuck in whatever mode it was last set to, or just not work. Instead the modes seem to switch. This doesn't seem that likely, but I could be wrong. I hope it's not this as it's a pain in the rear to replace, involving taking the whole steering column apart
Wiper motor: A short in the motor could cause odd behavior, I wouldn't expect it to look like this though. The wipers definitely look like they are working according to commands, at consistent speeds. I would think an issue with the motor would look like it's going at the wrong speed, or just not stopping or parking correctly
Relay: Buggy relays can cause all sorts of strange problems, so this is a definite possibility. I'm really hoping this is it, as it's a cheap and super easy fix. I've ordered a replacement as it's the easiest way to tell
Wiring issue: I wouldn't expect a wiring issue to lead to different modes operating. I am really hoping this isn't it as it will be a cast iron pain in the rear to diagnose
Front SAM module: this seems like the most likely possibility, as the code is saying there's a loss of connectivity to the motor, yet I would expect a motor or wiring issue to have different symptoms, and an issue with the stalk probably wouldn't bring up that code

So my order is relay, SAM, stalk, wiring and then motor. Am I missing something, or is there a way I can further narrow this down with testing?
EDIT: This all started happening on a long drive yesterday. I tried restarting the car on the way and this persisted, and just after I got home and did some troubleshooting it did the same odd behavior. This afternoon after the car sat overnight the wipers are back to normal. This eliminates wiring and the indicator stalk, as issues with these wouldn't just correct themselves.
I suspect something is overheating, only malfunctioning after it gets warm enough. The motor seems unlikely, that leaves the relay and the SAM module a the most likely culprits.

I would suspect the electronics within the wiper. While I've not dealt with MB on this, I've seen in other vehicles where the wipers go wonkey and it comes down to the electronics. Some from water ingress, while others have disconnects on the board. Just a thought.
